# Forwarding Refs: forwardedRef is always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an ant design `Table` component that I want `ref` to be attached to.

I want to be able to use the `tableRef` in HOC `withCustomPagination`'s lifecycle `componentDidUpdate` method.

Following the [React Docs Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components), that I could not clearly comprehend. I could cook up the following code:

*App.js*

```
import WrappedTable from '/path/to/file';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const tableRef = React.createRef();
    return (
      <WrappedTable ref={tableRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

*Table.js*

```
import withCustomPagination from '/path/to/file';

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }

  render() {
    <TableContainer ref={this.props.forwardedRef} />
  }
}

const WrappedTable = withCustomPagination(Table);
export default WrappedTable;
```

*withCustomPagination.js*

```
import CustomPagination from 'path/to/file';

const withCustomPagination = tableRef => Component => {
  class WithCustomPagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        rows: 1,
        dataLength: props.dataLength,
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      tableRef.current.state ..... //logic using ref, Error for this line
      this.state.rows ..... //some logic
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardedRef } = this.props;
      return (
        <Component {...this.state} ref={forwardedRef} />
        <CustomPagination />
      )
    }
  }
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <WithCustomPagination {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  });
}

export default withCustomPagination;
```

After debugging, I find that `forwardedRef` is always null.

[image: Debug session screenshot]

Comment: What is your react version ?

Comment: v 16.6.3, After further debugging the code I have found out that, `ref` is actually a `Connect` when I `console.log(tableRef)` in `App.js`, because I have used  `react-redux` connect function like this `export default connect(x,y)(WrappedTable)`. I am still debugging the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is happening in your HOC:

```
                              here
const withCustomPagination = tableRef => Component => {
```

You need to remove that parameter. The way to access to the ref prop is simply in your `componentDidUpdate` method like `forwardedRef` prop e.g:

```
import CustomPagination from 'path/to/file';

const withCustomPagination = Component => {
  class WithCustomPagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        rows: 1,
        dataLength: props.dataLength,
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      //You got the ref here
      console.log(forwardedRef.current)
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardedRef } = this.props;
      return (
        <Component {...this.state} ref={forwardedRef} />
        <CustomPagination />
      )
    }
  }
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <WithCustomPagination {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  });
}

export default withCustomPagination;
```

Also somethings to have in account are:

You should not create the ref in the render method because this method is raised every time you set a state. I recommend you to do it in the constructor:

```
import WrappedTable from '/path/to/file';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.reference = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <WrappedTable ref={this.reference} />
    )
  }
}
```

Also in you HOC render only one child or use `React.Fragment`. Besides do not forget the send the rest properties:

```
const withCustomPagination = Component => {
  class WithCustomPagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        rows: 1,
        dataLength: props.dataLength,
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      //You got the ref here
      console.log(forwardedRef.current)
    }

    render() {
      // Do not forget to send the rest of properties here like:
      const { forwardedRef, ...rest } = this.props;
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Component {...this.state} ref={forwardedRef} {...rest} />
          <CustomPagination />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <WithCustomPagination {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
  });
}

export default withCustomPagination;
```

**EDIT:**

Add the reference of the ref prop

```
import withCustomPagination from '/path/to/file';

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.reference = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    <TableContainer ref={this.reference} />
  }
}

const WrappedTable = withCustomPagination(Table);
export default WrappedTable;
```

Comment: I am not getting `forwardedRef` as the antd table element that I actually need, instead it is `Connect` when I export `export default connect(x,y)(WrappedTable)` from *Table.js*. If I remove connect, I am still not getting the desired element.

Comment: Do you need the `TableContainer` ref in the HOC?

Comment: Yes, it is the ant design Table component that I need.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `tableRef` in HOC `withCustomPagination`, I removed `const tableRef = React.createRef()` from *App.js* and the corresponding `ref = {tableRef}` lines.
I pass `tableRef` to HOC, curried, `withCustomPagination(tableRef)(NewGiftCardTable)`. I also removed all the *Forwarding Refs* logic in HOC, this I did because I needed access to `tableRef` only in HOC and not in *App.js*.

Added above removed lines to *Table.js*:

```
import withCustomPagination from '/path/to/file';

const tableRef = React.createRef(); 

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }

  render() {
    <TableContainer ref={tableRef} />
  }

const WrappedTable = withCustomPagination(tableRef)(Table);
export default WrappedTable;
```